# The Name Does not Exists in the Current Context

Tags: c#

I am relevantly new to C# coding. I am creating a Asp + C# website for C# learning and fun.I am stuck in a strange error.

**What I am doing.**
Getting username from a textbox, Converting the name to the char arrary, and then trying to join add arrays as per their value described on the switch statement.

but, it is showing me red squiggly lines in all my switch statement, showing me , The Name Does not Exists in the Current Context .

Any clue, how to fix it?

```
name = TextBoxName.Text.ToString();
var number = 0;
char[] arr = name.ToCharArray();
foreach (var nameChar in arr)
{
    switch (nameChar)
    {
        case A:
            number += 1;
        case B:
            number += 2;
        case C:
            number += 3;
        case D:
            number += 4;
        case E:
            number += 5;
        case F:
            number += 5;
        case G:
            number += 7;
        case H:
            number += 8;
        case I:
            number += 9;
        case J:
            number += 10;
        case K:
            number += 11;
        case L:
            number += 12;
        case M:
            number += 13;
        case N:
            number += 14;
        case O:
            number += 15;
        case P:
            number += 16;
        case Q:
            number += 17;
        case R:
            number += 18;
        case S:
            number += 19;
        case T:
            number += 20;
        case U:
            number += 21;
        case V:
            number += 22;
        case W:
            number += 23;
        case X:
            number += 24;
        case Y:
            number += 25;
        case Z:
            number += 26;
        default:
    }
};
```

Comment: Ho Fyodor, I added double quotes, but, it was showing the same error.

Comment: deleted my comment with inaccurate suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Switch you can check on  msnd over here : [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

you need to do like this, my mean to say you misssed quote here

```
  case 'A':
```

and you also missed break statment here so it will be like

```
     case 'A':
        number += 1;
        break;
    case 'B':
        number += 2;
        break;
```

Answer (score 4):

Others have pointed out your error, but please don't use code like that. Try something like this instead:

```
const string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char[] arr = name.ToUpper().ToCharArray();
foreach (var nameChar in arr)
{
    number += letters.IndexOf(nameChar) + 1;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

To use chars in C# you need to use the apostrophies. And to separate different cases between each other you need to you "break" at the end of each case:

```
case 'A':
     number += 1;
     break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone, thanks for your valuable inputs and suggestions.

It is solved, and the issues were.

- missing `break;`
- Need to add `''` in A: `'A'`
- In foreach loop I have mentioned `var nameChar` and I have changed it
  to `char namechar`
- and need to add `.ToUpper` in the `textbox.Text`

When we learning something new, mistakes do happen :) and thanks for correcting them.

Comment: dont forget to upvote and accept anser that helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string use `"A"`

```
       case "A":
            number += 1;
         break;
```

or simply

```
           case 'A':
                number += 1;
             break;
```

Answer (score -2):

You are giving potential variable names not characters as the value is expected so tr 'A' instead of A etc

Answer (score -2):

you should use 'A' instead of A